# How to interpolate (x,y,h) points within a polygon shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, r, interpolation

I have 2D points with (x,y) coordinates. Each point has an associated height value 'h'.

These randomly distributed points lie inside a polygon shapefile. My desired output is to interpolate the heights across the polygon using these 2D points. Where, the final result is a polygon shapefile with interpolated heights.

How can I do this in ArcGIS or R?

Comment: Are you sure you want a polygon shapefile with interpolated heights? It is not clear what you are asking. A polygon covering your points would contain just the average of the h values, so you don't even need to interpolate. If what you want is a surface with a gradient this is a raster file, not a polygon shapefile. Could you clarify what you ask?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in two stages.  Create a raster by interpolating your heights (see [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/interpolate-from-point-cloud.htm)).  Ensure the raster resolution is the same as the point spacing you want in your output shapefile.  When you have created the DEM, [convert that to points](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012696) (one point per raster cell gives you a regular set of points across your polygon - you can clip to fit as required).